# c# tab wrapped string

Tags: c#, tabs, word-wrap

I am writing out a large string (around 100 lines) to a text file, and would like the entire block of text tabbed.

```
WriteToOutput("\t" + strErrorOutput);
```

The line I am using above only tabs the first line of the text. How can I indent/tab the entire string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all linebreaks by linebreak followed by a tab:

```
WriteToOutput("\t" + strErrorOutput.Replace("\n", "\n\t"));
```

Comment: Thanks...Is there a way I can make strings that are too long to fit on one line, also be tabbed? Right now, all new lines are tabbed, but some of the longer lines are wrapping around without any indent

Comment: take a look at this [snippet for a wrapping string extension method](http://bryan.reynoldslive.com/post/Wrapping-string-data.aspx) that returns a list of strings

Comment: ^^ dead link from 2013

Answer (score 1):

```
File.WriteAllLines(FILEPATH,input.Split(new string[] {"\n","\r"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                 .Select(x=>"\t"+x));
```

Answer (score 1):

To do so you would have to have a limited line length (ie <100 characters) at which point this issue becomes easy.

```
public string ConvertToBlock(string text, int lineLength)
{
    string output = "\t";

    int currentLineLength = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < text.Length; index++)
    {
        if (currentLineLength < lineLength)
        {
            output += text[index];
            currentLineLength++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (index != text.Length - 1)
            {
                if (text[index + 1] != ' ')
                {
                    int reverse = 0;
                    while (text[index - reverse] != ' ')
                    {
                        output.Remove(index - reverse - 1, 1);
                        reverse++;
                    }
                    index -= reverse;
                    output += "\n\t";
                    currentLineLength = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
 }
```

This will convert any text into a block of text that is broken up into lines of length `lineLength` and that all start with a tab and end with a newline.

Comment: This function has at least one bug in it.  The Remove function does not modify the current string, but returns a new one.  This could does not assign the result of `output.Remove` back to `output`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a copy of your string for output that replaces CRLF with CRLF + TAB.  And the write that string to output (still prefixed with the initial TAB).

```
strErrorOutput = strErrorOutput.Replace("\r\n", "\r\n\t");
WriteToOutput("\t" + strErrorOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're here looking for a way to word-wrap a string to a certain width, and have each line indented (as I was), here's a solution as an extension method.  Roughly based on the answer above, but uses regular expressions to split the original text into word and spaces pairs, then rejoins them, adding line breaks and indentation as needed.  (Does not sanity check inputs, so you'll need to add that if needed)

```cs
public string ToBlock(this string text, int lineLength, string indent="")
{
    var r = new Regex("([^ ]+)?([ ]+)?");
    var matches = r.Match(text);
    if (!matches.Success)
    {
        return text;
    }
    string output = indent;
    int currentLineLength = indent.Length;
    while (matches.Success)
    {
        var groups = matches.Groups;
        var nextLength = groups[0].Length;
        if (currentLineLength + nextLength <= lineLength)
        {
            output += groups[0];
            currentLineLength += groups[0].Length;
        }
        else
        {
            if (currentLineLength + groups[1].Length > lineLength)
            {
                output += "\n" + indent + groups[0];
                currentLineLength = indent.Length + groups[0].Length;
            }
            else
            {
                output += groups[1] + "\n" + indent;
                currentLineLength = indent.Length;
            }
        }
        matches = matches.NextMatch();
    }
    return output;
}
```